# Filtrar string REGEX C#

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho uma string que retorna todo o conteudo de uma página html.

Nesta pagina, tem a seguinte linha:

```
<input style="width: 2.3em;" id="nacional" value="3,48" type="text">
```

Preciso somente do valor que está em `value`, ou seja, `3,48`, lembrando que este valor muda automaticamente todos os dias.

Como posso filtrar esta linha e pegar o valor?

Answer (score 3):

[Fiz um Regexr com seu padrão](http://regexr.com/3dd4s). A expressão regular é:

```
value=\"([\d,]+)\"
```

No C# ela fica um pouco diferente.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"value=""([\d,]+)""");
```

Feito isso, basta selecionar o grupo 1 (grupo 0 é a correspondência inteira encontrada). Ou seja:

```
var match = regex.Match("<input style=\"width: 2.3em;\" id=\"nacional\" value=\"3,48\" type=\"text\">");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kojUO7).

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo que retorna qualquer caractere entre aspas duplas ou apóstrofo, dentro do atributo value.

```
value=['"](.*?)['"]
```

Comment: e como eu poderia implementar nesta linha?                                MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches()

Comment: Este é apenas o pattern, qualquer dúvida vale a pena dar uma olhada sobre [Regex C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)